# Webpack --watch doesn't watch

Tags: reactjs, webpack

I am trying to get a dev environment set up so that I can do [these tutorials](https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PLoYCgNOIyGABj2GQSlDRjgvXtqfDxKm5b) from LearnCode.academy.

When I run `webpack` it works and I get:

```
$ webpack 
Hash: fdcd8e6850d6c4402a7e
Version: webpack 1.13.0
Time: 4688ms
        Asset     Size  Chunks             Chunk Names
client.min.js  1.75 MB       0  [emitted]  main
+ 163 hidden modules
$
```

But when I run `webpack --watch` exactly the same thing happens. The desired effect is that it'd keep watching until I stopped it.

The sample repo is [here](https://github.com/learncodeacademy/react-js-tutorials)

Any ideas what to do?

Answer (score 0):

The article [Beginner’s guide to Webpack](https://medium.com/@dabit3/beginner-s-guide-to-webpack-b1f1a3638460#.5i5arh8lx) give the option of putting watch into the `webpack.config.js` file. Like so:

```
module.exports = {
  entry: "./app.js",
  output: {
    filename: "bundle.js"
  }, 
  watch: true
}
```

I'm not wild about this, but it seems to work.